# How to get coordinates of some points in my .TMX map? - LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm working on my game in LibGDX. I loaded my .TMX map to game, set a camera and a viewport.

`gameCam = new OrthographicCamera();
gamePort = new FitViewport(Marina.V_WIDTH / Marina.PPM, Marina.V_HEIGHT / Marina.PPM, gameCam)
gameCam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
gameCam.position.x = 2.08f;// Here you have the starting cords of my camera.
gameCam.position.y = 1.36f;`

The problem is, when player touch one of the four egdes the camera is moving (4.16/-4.16 on X and 2.72/-2.72 on Y). For example, from 2.08/1.36 to 2.08+4.16/1.36 when the player touch the right edge.

My question is how to get cords of green points?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Zjt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the edges of what the camera is seeing, you simply have to do this:

Left edge: `camera.position.x - (viewport.getWorldWidth() / 2)`

Right edge: `camera.position.x + (viewport.getWorldWidth() / 2)`

Top edge: `camera.position.y - (viewport.getWorldHeight() / 2)`

Bottom edge: `camera.position.y + (viewport.getWorldHeight() / 2)`

I think I have answered your question